# Android Duplicate Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to add the unmano sliding up panel library to my android project and I get this error when I try to run the project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is my dependencies list:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'gson-*.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
}
```

From what I understand from reading on other posts is that there is a duplicate file causing this build error. Can someone help me understand what I need to do to fix this? How do I find the duplicate files? Is there any gradle command I can use to detect and remove duplicates? Thanks

EDIT: Here's my lib folder contents:

```
bolts-android-1.2.1.jar
gson-2.3.1.jar
Parse-1.10.0.jar
YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you have included same library file twice

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'gson-*.jar')`

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')`

So it seems that `gson-*.jar` and `Parse-*.jar` are included twice.

**Edit:**

As you said the problem is with umano sliding up library, then it should be the problem of its dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

And I have check `com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library`, it has the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

so you included 2 versions of support library, and thus having the problem.

```
compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
```

To fix the problem, replace the line above to the one below.

```
compile('com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1') { 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

In addition to the above, setup multidex following the guide below

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Hey Derek, I removed them and it's still showing the error. It only appears when I try to include the unman library. I guess I should've noted this but a few weeks ago I tried adding it via importing (due to my lack of understanding how Android Studio worked at the time) and then I deleted it thinking I didn't need it. Could this be that I did not fully delete the previous import?

Comment: I tried your edit and I'm still getting the same error. Should I be including the exclude in the other libraries?

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake before, it is the com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library which has the conflict support-v4 library, updated my edit

Comment: It's alright, but no luck. Still getting the same error

Comment: also what is in your lib folder?

Comment: Added lib folder contents to the post, and nope that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88587/discussion-between-derek-fung-and-ryan).

Answer (score 2):

Your first dependency

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

and these

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'gson-*.jar')
```

compile same librarys. First one compiles all the jar file inside libs folder where gson and and Parse are stored.
And the other two again adds the gson and Parse library.

So simple remove them and add something like this.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
......
compile files('libs/gson-*.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-*.jar')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Aawaz, thanks but it didn't. I wrote this on Derek's post: I removed them and it's still showing the error. It only appears when I try to include the unman library. I guess I should've noted this but a few weeks ago I tried adding it via importing (due to my lack of understanding how Android Studio worked at the time) and then I deleted it thinking I didn't need it. Could this be that I did not fully delete the previous import?

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Might help.

Answer (score 1):

Make `multiDexEnabled` to  true in your build.grade file, in `defaultConfig`.

Comment: This seemed to fix it but what does multidex do? I'll choose this as the answer once you can explain to me... thanks! EDIT: nevermind, now it crashes even though it can load up for the time being.

Comment: Ah.. mine was fixed with that... I don't know why but as far I know, when duplicated dex file are compiled, they throw an error..